# Selenium locating input (Angular.JS)

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I just started using Selenium to automate e2e testing. How am I able to locate following input?

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" data-ng-model="model.campaign.name" required="" data-ng-disabled="model.isDisabled">
```

So far tried to get the input by locating @ng-repeat, unfortunately with no luck. And the class can't work :)

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@ng-repeat='model.campaign.name']")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You'll find you get a lot more help with your questions, by posting a thorough description of your problem, and what you have attempted so far.

Comment: @marcel tried to get the data-ng-model

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@ng-repeat='model.campaign.name']")

unfortunately no luck

Comment: I'm not super familiar with selenium, but have you tried `"//input[@data-ng-model='model.campaign.name]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with combination of the xpath

```
//input[@data-ng-model='model.campaign.name' and @class='input-xlarge ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required']
```

you can also try **`execute_script`**

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-ng-model='model.campaign.name' and @class='input-xlarge ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required']") 
//operation you wanted it is just an example
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```